# xlrd to loop through multiple workbooks in a folder

Tags: python, excel, xlrd

I'm working on a script that pulls certain rows of data from multiple Excel workbooks in a folder (the critical sheet has the same name in every workbook). This code seems only to process/print results from the first file in the folder:

```
import os
import xlrd



for root, dirs, files in os.walk('/Users/123/Desktop/drivingtests'):
    xlsfiles=[ _ for _ in files if _.endswith('.xlsx') ]
for xlsfile in xlsfiles:
    workbook = xlrd.open_workbook(os.path.join(root,xlsfile))
    worksheet = workbook.sheet_by_name('Sheet1')
for row in range(worksheet.nrows):
    workbook = xlrd.open_workbook(os.path.join(root,xlsfile))
    worksheet = workbook.sheet_by_name('Sheet1')
    if worksheet.row_values(row)[0] == 'bike':
        print worksheet.row_values(row)
```

What should be done to have the script process every workbook in the folder?

Answer (score 2):

The answer is "indentions are important". When indented like the code below, it loops through all the files in the folder.

```
import os
import xlrd



for root, dirs, files in os.walk('/Users/123/Desktop/drivingtests'):
    xlsfiles=[ _ for _ in files if _.endswith('.xlsx') ]
    for xlsfile in xlsfiles:
        workbook = xlrd.open_workbook(os.path.join(root,xlsfile))
        worksheet = workbook.sheet_by_name('Sheet1')
        for row in range(worksheet.nrows):
            if worksheet.row_values(row)[0] == 'bike':
                print worksheet.row_values(row)
```